# Flutter unselect RadioListTile buttons

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have been trying to figure out where my mistake is for days but still couldn't solve it. Absolute novice in Flutter and I building multiple choice quiz app.  I have multiple choice question screen which imports the radiolisttile choices from radio_button.dart file shown below.

Everything works except I cannot unselect a button once it's selected. In other words if I click each button all of them are selected.

```
 import "package:flutter/material.dart";

 class RB extends StatefulWidget {
 RB({this.choice, this.value});

 final String choice;
 final String value;

@override
_RBState createState() => _RBState();

}
class _RBState extends State<RB> {
bool dense=false;
 String _selection = '';
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return   Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Material(
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: RadioListTile(
      title: Text(widget.choice,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,),),
      value: widget.choice,
      groupValue: _selection,
      dense: dense,
      activeColor: Colors.green,
      onChanged:( val) { setState(() { _selection = val; print(val);}); },

    ),
  ),
 );
 }
}

Here the question_screen snippet
 Column(
 children: <Widget>[
 Container(child: RB(choice:'A',value:'All of above',)),
 Container(child: RB(choice:'B',value:'None of the above'))
```

Answer (score 6):

Now, in Sep, 2020, the correct answer should be using `toggleable` attribute.

```
RadioListTile(
            title: Text("xxx"),
            value: index,
            groupValue: _seletedIndex,
            toggleable: true,
            onChanged: (value) {
              onAlertChange(value, alert);
            },
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

because you have create group value for every single widget ,you have to share the group value with each radio list tile not to create one for each radio button.
1- move the *_selection* variable up in the widget tree to be shared for each **RB** you have and pass it to every **RB**.
2-add another parameter to the **RB** class of type Function with string parameter and pass it to the onchanged parameter for each **RB**

your **RB** class will look something like this :

```
 class RB extends StatefulWidget {
 RB({this.choice, this.value,this.onchanged});
 final Function (String value) onChanged;
  final String groupValue;
 final String choice;
 final String value;

@override
_RBState createState() => _RBState();

}
class _RBState extends State<RB> {
bool dense=false;
 String _selection = '';
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return   Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Material(
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: RadioListTile(
      title: Text(widget.choice,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,),),
      value: widget.choice,
      groupValue: widget.groupValue,
      dense: dense,
      activeColor: Colors.green,
      onChanged:widget.onChanged,

    ),
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

now in the parent widget :

```
    Column(
     children: <Widget>[
     Container(child: RB(choice:'A',value:'All of 
       above',groupValue:"youValue",onChanged(value){
_selection = value;
setState((){});
})),
```

of course you should seperate the onchanged function to helper function for the seek of readability and flexibility.

Comment: Thank you but it seems it's not working.It doesn't select any of the radio buttons now.

Comment: Sorry, where do you use _selection' I initialized groupValue:_selection and it works , no idea  if this is best practice.

Comment: i'm glad that it worked , the best practice is to move your logic out of the ui , search for state management in flutter , you will find many options , they all achieve the same target , choose what you find best for you

Answer (score 1):

**Wrap your `RadioListTile` with `GestureDetector`**

```
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _selection = '';
              });
            },
            child: RadioListTile(
            //...
```

Comment: Thank you,   it selects and deselect but all buttons could be in selected mode at the same time. How can I enforce that only one of could be selected at a time. Thanks again

Comment: `onTap`  checks the entered deselection value.

Answer (score 0):

`RadioListTile(toggaleable: true)`To unselect the selected radio item use **toggleable: true,** inside the RadioListTile()